# Detect Simple Touch Gestures

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

Can anyone explain on how to detect simple touch gestures in a WinRT app? I tried using the `GestureRecognizer` class but it didn't work:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer gr = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();
        gr.CrossSliding += gr_CrossSliding;
        gr.Dragging += gr_Dragging;
        gr.Holding += gr_Holding;
        gr.ManipulationCompleted += gr_ManipulationCompleted;
        gr.ManipulationInertiaStarting += gr_ManipulationInertiaStarting;
        gr.ManipulationStarted += gr_ManipulationStarted;
        gr.ManipulationUpdated += gr_ManipulationUpdated;
        gr.RightTapped += gr_RightTapped;
        gr.Tapped += gr_Tapped;
        gr.GestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotate | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateX | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateY |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScale | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotateInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScaleInertia |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.Tap;

    }

    void gr_Tapped(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.TappedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_Tapped");
    }
    void gr_RightTapped(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.RightTappedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_RightTapped");
    }
    void gr_Holding(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.HoldingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_Holding");
    }
    void gr_Dragging(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.DraggingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_Dragging");
    }
    void gr_CrossSliding(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlidingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_CrossSliding");
    }
    void gr_ManipulationUpdated(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_ManipulationUpdated");
    }
    void gr_ManipulationStarted(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_ManipulationStarted");
    }
    void gr_ManipulationCompleted(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_ManipulationCompleted");
    }
    void gr_ManipulationInertiaStarting(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.ManipulationInertiaStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("gr_ManipulationInertiaStarting");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you've added a handler to the Tapped event.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you will notice the MainPage Class has its own Manipulation Events which you can use without creating a seperate `GestureRecognizer`. You can enable it by setting `this.ManipulationMode` to  `ManipulationModes.All`. This will allow you to see responses on the MainPages `Tapped`, `RightTapped`, `ManipulationStarting`, `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta` and `ManipulationCompleted` Events.

As far as getting the GestureRecongnizer to work according to this [Blog](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/winrt/) and this [MSDN Forum Posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/0dad4881-da1c-4db9-be8d-a9324a233662) you will need to handle the MainPage's `PointerMoved`, `PointerReleased` and `PointerPressed` events like so.

```
Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer gr = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();  

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.PointerPressed += MainPage_PointerPressed;
    this.PointerMoved += MainPage_PointerMoved;
    this.PointerReleased += MainPage_PointerReleased;
    gr.CrossSliding += gr_CrossSliding;    
    gr.Dragging += gr_Dragging;    
    gr.Holding += gr_Holding;    
    gr.ManipulationCompleted += gr_ManipulationCompleted;    
    gr.ManipulationInertiaStarting += gr_ManipulationInertiaStarting;    
    gr.ManipulationStarted += gr_ManipulationStarted;    
    gr.ManipulationUpdated += gr_ManipulationUpdated;    
    gr.RightTapped += gr_RightTapped;    
    gr.Tapped += gr_Tapped;    
    gr.GestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotate | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateX | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateY |    
    Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScale | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotateInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScaleInertia |    
    Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.Tap; 
}

void MainPage_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
    if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
    {
        gr.ProcessUpEvent(ps[0]);
        e.Handled = true;
        gr.CompleteGesture();
    }
}

void MainPage_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gr.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(null));
    e.Handled = true;
}

void MainPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
    if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
    {
        gr.ProcessDownEvent(ps[0]);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

---

According to the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465299.aspx) you need to enable the [CrossSlide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.crosssliding.aspx) Event by adding it to your GestureRecongnizer and setting up the [CrossSlideThresholds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.crossslidethresholds.aspx) and Direction.
From last link:

> CrossSlide must be set in the GestureSettings property to support CrossSliding.
>   CrossSliding distance thresholds are disabled by default. Use CrossSlideThresholds to set these values.

example:

```
Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds cst = new Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds();
cst.SelectionStart = 2;
cst.SpeedBumpStart = 3;
cst.SpeedBumpEnd = 4;
cst.RearrangeStart = 5;
gr.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
gr.CrossSlideThresholds = cst;
gr.CrossSliding += gr_CrossSliding;
```

and make sure it is added to your `GestureSettings`

```
gr.GestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotate | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateX |
                     Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScale | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotateInertia |
                     Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScaleInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia |
                     Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.Tap | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.CrossSlide;
```

Comment: Will this change the GestureSettings for the whole application?