# MouseMove event alternative in Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need a requirement to move my rectangle around the Grid. In WPF or Silverlight , we can use MouseMove event to capture the points to get my rectangle to be moved. But in Windows Phone 7 which event will be highly suitable to do these kind of scenario. Any one can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7 you can handle manipulation events as described in [How to: Handle Manipulation Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

In Windows 8 (but not in Windows Phone 8) you could perhaps use the [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241937.aspx), as described in this question: [Detect Simple Touch Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12269725/1136211).