# gesture recognizer - slide up and down

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gesture

i tried getting this to work for many hours, but i just don't understand what i am doing wrong =(
On the internet and especially this side are some solutions but i couldn't get them running. i.e. there was a similar question, but he used `GestureListener` which doesn't seem to be supported for windows phone 8.1, or maybe i am missing sth.
Also i am confused which gesture i should use (dragging / crossSliding / Manipulation-Updated)

So, what i want is rather simple. I want to wipe from top to bottom / from bottom to top and get a number back, like the distance of movement. Also some sort of determination if movement was up or down.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        GestureRecognizer gr = new GestureRecognizer();
        gr.Dragging += gr_dragging;
        gr.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.Drag;

    }

    void gr_dragging(GestureRecognizer sender, DraggingEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("dragging");
    }
```

I don't know whats wrong here, but i never get to see the `Debug` message. If somebody can please point me in the right direction, that would be great !

Comment: check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269725/detect-simple-touch-gestures), also note that WP8.1 != WPF, WP8.1 uses WinRT(assuming you aren't using silverlight or HTML5/JS) which is the same as windows store apps

Comment: WP8.1 != WPF, i wasn't aware of that. just recently started developing. And i worked through that question as well, though i couldn't get most of the gestures to fire their debug message.

Comment: i am getting those `C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL Cannot find or open the PDB file. ` error messages. Does it mean, i havn't correctly installed my VS or WP8.1 Plugin? Is it Code or System related?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".