# Longpress in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm porting an app to Univeral Windows Platform (Windows 10).

Android has a [`onLongPress` event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html). Is there an equivalent for UWP?

I found there is a [`Holding` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding.aspx) which I tried to use something like this:

```
private void Rectangle_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HoldingState == HoldingState.Started)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Holding started!");
    }
}
```

Problem is the event is not triggered on Windows Desktop, when mouse is used instead of touch.

Comment: You should try mouse event for case of desktop application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mouse input doesn't produce Holding events by default, you should use [RightTapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.righttapped) event to show the context menu, it is triggered when user long presses in a touch device and right clicks in a mouse device.

Take a look at [GestureRecognizer.Holding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.holding.aspx) and [Detect Simple Touch Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269725/detect-simple-touch-gestures), you can achieve that using the following code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer = new GestureRecognizer();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        gestureRecognizer.GestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.HoldWithMouse;         
    }

    void gestureRecognizer_Holding(GestureRecognizer sender, HoldingEventArgs args)
    {
        MyTextBlock.Text = "Hello";
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gestureRecognizer.Holding += gestureRecognizer_Holding;
    }

    private void Grid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
        if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
        {
            gestureRecognizer.ProcessDownEvent(ps[0]);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Grid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gestureRecognizer.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(null));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Grid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
        if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
        {
            gestureRecognizer.ProcessUpEvent(ps[0]);
            e.Handled = true;
            gestureRecognizer.CompleteGesture();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not to open a context menu, so the right-click doesn't feel so natural.

Comment: I have added [GestureRecognizer.Holding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.holding.aspx), and it will solve your problem.

Comment: @holmis83, if it have helped, please consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry for delay. I accept it although `ProcessDownEvent` raises exception "Failed to start tracking the pointer, because it is already being tracked." during some circumstances.

Comment: @holmis83, thanks, then I would suggest you open another question for the exception if it is still unresolved.

Comment: @holmis83 I disagree with your "feel so natural" view. I think holding to open a menu is more unnatural on a computer. People know the right click these days even without context menus.